# How can I pass data from C# to xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I have this xaml code and need to set Points dynamically from C# code.

```
<Style x:Key="Mystyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>

                            <Polygon  Points="0,0 0,100 50,200" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                         Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Um. Data binding using the ViewModel? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @Moataz A.Mohammed what happened? My solution is not working?

Comment: ya , i can't know why now I'm trying using XamlReader. because NotificationObject class in windows phone not in normal WPF dlls

Comment: NotificationObject is in Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll assembly and you can use this class in normal WPF application, not only in Windows Phone. On the other side you can implement interfejs INotifyPropertyChanged and everything will be ok. I used this class because it is faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM solution:

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="PolygonBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Mystyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Polygon Points="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource Mystyle}" Tag="{Binding PointsSource}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind file:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

ViewModel file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace PolygonBinding
{
    class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PointsSource.Add(new Point { X = 0, Y =0 });
            PointsSource.Add(new Point { X = 0, Y = 100 });
            PointsSource.Add(new Point { X = 50, Y = 200 });            
        }

        private PointCollection _pointsSource = new PointCollection();
        public PointCollection PointsSource
        {
            get { return _pointsSource; }
            set { _pointsSource = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => PointsSource); }
        }
    }       
}
```